# How to write the contents from mapper into file - Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How to write the contents of mapper into file. Is this fine.

```
public class MyMapper extends
        Mapper<Object, Text, Text, MatrixWritable > {
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

  Path inputfile = new Path("in/map");
  BufferedWriter getdatabuffer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(inputfile)));
  if(value.toString()!= null){
             getdatabuffer.write(value.toString());
         }
             getdatabuffer.close();
```

If my inputfile is splited whether the above code works fine?

In reducer i am combining all the mapper data.

EDIT

```
        Path inputfile = new Path("in/map");
             FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(inputfile);
         if(value.toString()!= null){
            out.writeBytes(value.toString());
         }
            out.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapper task run concurrently on multiple nodes in the Hadoop cluster. Your method of writing with normal Java Writer classes will not work just because you need to use HDFS API to write the data.

Instead in the map method use `context.write()` to write the data to HDFS files.

Comment: Thanxs Ankur. I am doing further computation after the file read in mapper.i need to knw wether the above code is perfect for input spilts?

Comment: oh ok.But i wonder why it run successfully for a 100 KB file in cluster with the above code. But wen i tried with 90 MB file it gave me Lease Mismatch exception.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but it seems in your first case just one mapper task was getting created as the data was quite small, but in the second one multiple task will be spawned.

Comment: ys that might be the reason Ankur.so how to write data using HDFS API?Anyway i will try changing n see wether it works or not.

Comment: Is it HadoopDFSFileReadWrite?

Comment: do you mean context.write()?

Comment: NO ...you told me to use HDFS API to write the data.so i should change the java writer to FSDataOutputStream. right? pls see my edit

Comment: Why dont you better use context.write()? If you use HDFS Api in mapper, you may need to handle concurrency issues manually as multiple mappers run concurrently.

Comment: I am little confused Ankur: let me ask...actually this context.write () is done for reducer input na?ie after all the mapper computation we will be sending the data to reducer through context.write. isn't it like that?

Comment: No necessarily. You can configure your Job to write the mapper output to HDFS. Also you can have map-reduce job with just mappers (no reducers). This is generally used to perform some kind of join operation generally known as 'Mapper side join'.

Comment: Thx Ankur for spending ur valid time answering my doubts